# Create .exe file in C# Window Application include SQL Server database (version 2014)

Tags: c#, sql-server, installation

The problem is I already have a database connected from SQL Server 2014. Now I want to create `.exe` file of my project (C# Window Application) with database for client machine. I want to install `.exe` file to the client machine without installing SQL Server on the client machine. So how I can access database file and which file want for `.exe` file and what is the location of database file (for backup). Thanks

Comment: why don't you use sqlite instead?

Comment: If you want to use SQL Server you have to install it, there is no way around that.

Comment: i don't about sqllite so how i can  if i want to convert sql server databse to sqllite .thanks

Comment: Is the SQL Database supposed to be shared by clients? Or do you want to have one _local_ DB _per client_? If the latter, start looking for [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15) or some single-file DB like [SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli). Mind that there are several different ways to actually _use_ SQLite. I'd guess if you have been using SQL Server, the transition to Local DB should be easier.

Comment: In most installations, the SQL Server is hosted on a central server and is shared between multiple client applications (installed on different machines) who all connect to the same shared database. Is that your situation? Or should each client really have its own separate database, with no shared data?

Comment: How i can attack  .bak or mdf file to the project setup